# MongoDB/Mongoose Connection Error when Dbname is used in the connection string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

A NodeJS app uses mongoose 5.6.0 to connect to MongoDB 4.0.10 which runs on localhost inside a docker container.

The connection can be established when we use

```
const mongoUri = 'mongodb://admin:mypassword@127.0.0.1:27017'
mongoose.connect(mongoUri)
```

**Problem:** We start getting authentication errors when we include the name of the database we are connecting to. There is no problem using Python to connect to the same MongoDB database.

```
const mongoUri = 'mongodb://admin:mypassword@127.0.0.1:27017/my-db'
mongoose.connect(mongoUri)
```

and also tried

```
const mongoUri = 'mongodb://admin:mypassword@127.0.0.1:27017/my-db'
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

> > UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.

Why is it unable to make the connection and how can we solve this problem?

### Update

Found the solution to be

```
const mongoUri = 'mongodb://admin:mypassword@127.0.0.1:27017'
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'my-db' })
```

Why must the `dbname` be passed as an option instead of including it in the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me, thanks.

`var result = await mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017/', {useNewUrlParser: true,dbName: 'my-db'})`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Add `?authSource=admin` to URI string or use `{authSource:"admin"}`

```
const mongoUri = 'mongodb://admin:mypassword@127.0.0.1:27017/my-db?authSource=admin'
mongoose.connect(mongoUri)
```

Follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68137961/12280326 for detailed explanation.